# Dropdown menu box size

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I have a question about the dropdown menu size. If the title in the dropdown is long, it moves to the bottom line. I want it to increase the width of the Dropdown menu size. How can I do that. Below you can find the photo of the dropdown menu and the corresponding codes.Thanks for your answers.
[Dropdown Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDgCk.jpg)

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Created By CodingNepal -->
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Responsive Drop-down Menu Bar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <div class="logo">
CodingNepal</div>
<label for="btn" class="icon">
        <span class="fa fa-bars"></span>
      </label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="btn">
      <ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li>
          <label for="btn-1" class="show">Features +</label>
          <a href="#">Features</a>
          <input type="checkbox" id="btn-1">
          <ul>
<li><a href="#">Pages</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Elements</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Icons</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>
          <label for="btn-2" class="show">Services +</label>
          <a href="#">Services</a>
          <input type="checkbox" id="btn-2">
          <ul>
<li><a href="#">Web Design and some information</a></li>
<li><a href="#">App Design</a></li>
<li>
              <label for="btn-3" class="show">More +</label>
              <a href="#">More <span class="fa fa-plus"></span></a>
              <input type="checkbox" id="btn-3">
              <ul>
<li><a href="#">Submenu-1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Submenu-2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Submenu-3</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
    <div class="content">
      <header>Responsive Drop-down Menu Bar</header>
      <p>
HTML and CSS (Media Query)</p>
</div>
<script>
      $('.icon').click(function(){
        $('span').toggleClass("cancel");
      });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,600,700&display=swap');
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  user-select: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
body{
  background: #f2f2f2;
}
nav{
  background: #1b1b1b;
}
nav:after{
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
nav .logo{
  float: left;
  color: white;
  font-size: 27px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 70px;
  padding-left: 60px;
}
nav ul{
  float: right;
  margin-right: 40px;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}
nav ul li{
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #1b1b1b;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
nav ul li a{
  color: white;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 8px 15px;
}
nav ul li a:hover{
  color: cyan;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow:  0 0 5px #33ffff,
               0 0 10px #66ffff;
}
nav ul ul li a:hover{
  box-shadow: none;
}
nav ul ul{
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
  border-top: 3px solid cyan;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: top .3s;
}
nav ul ul ul{
  border-top: none;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul{
  top: 70px;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
nav ul ul li{
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 150px;
  float: none;
  display: list-item;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
nav ul ul li a{
  line-height: 50px;
}
nav ul ul ul li{
  position: relative;
  top: -60px;
  left: 150px;
}
.show,.icon,input{
  display: none;
}
.fa-plus{
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}
@media all and (max-width: 968px) {
  nav ul{
    margin-right: 0px;
    float: left;
  }
  nav .logo{
    padding-left: 30px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .show + a, ul{
    display: none;
  }
  nav ul li,nav ul ul li{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  nav ul li a:hover{
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  .show{
    display: block;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    line-height: 70px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .show:hover{
    color: cyan;
  }
  .icon{
    display: block;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 40px;
    line-height: 70px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 25px;
  }
  nav ul ul{
    top: 70px;
    border-top: 0px;
    float: none;
    position: static;
    display: none;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  nav ul ul a{
    padding-left: 40px;
  }
  nav ul ul ul a{
    padding-left: 80px;
  }
  nav ul ul ul li{
    position: static;
  }
  [id^=btn]:checked + ul{
    display: block;
  }
  nav ul ul li{
    border-bottom: 0px;
  }
  span.cancel:before{
    content: '\f00d';
  }
}
.content{
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  text-align: center;
}
header{
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
p{
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to set a width to the `<li>`of the drop menu? Try using the Browser's debug (you can open using F12) by editing the element's properties within the debug window.

Comment: When ı changed this prop nav ul ul li {width:250px} this problem fixed. But now another problem arises. There is a problem the submenu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put those two styles on your code. the reason for your issue is not specify the width of inner list.

```
    nav ul li ul {
        width: fit-content;
    }

    nav ul li ul li {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
    }
```

[image]

in your stylesheet there is some bad practices without defining any class names for your styles. it is hard to find when add more styles. you can use ids or classes and tones of ways to make it easy.

Comment: thanks for answers. When i cliked "more" there is some problem did you notice that